# How to make Process within Background worker to exit on CancellationPending event

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have an Application consisting of UI and Background worker.

Background worker does the following tasks:

1. Create a process and calls external binaries - using System.Diagnostic.Process.
2. Wait for this process to exit.
3. Update the UI with the data.

The issue here is if external exe hangs. Their is no way to cancel my background process. 
Since my background worker is busy waiting for other processes to complete, the cancellation token cannot be used. To resolve this issue, I used a timeout for my process. After this application closed.

My question is there any way to cancel the process(Called by background worker) to stop on setting the Cancellation event.

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: You can always [Kill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.kill) the process.

Comment: What is the reason to do not use cancellation token?

Comment: @stefan yes , But I need to handle it through application and kill only if process hangs

Comment: @DIlshodK , Cancellation token does not work since background worker gets busy waiting for process to exit.

Comment: I need a suggestion if setting timeout for WaitToExit is good option or do we have any other better option . So we need not worry on deciding max limit for timeout

Comment: @ApoorvaRaju You need to find a way to detect the process hangs? If you can determine that, than you can take proper action (by killing or cancelling or whatever).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can implement this logic using https://github.com/jamesmanning/RunProcessAsTask . With this library you can

1. specify cancellation token with timeout
2. await process as an ordinal task without blocking a thread.

Comment: thanks a lot for this suggestion this will help me at least unblock my worker